# Android ContentResolver not reliable

Tags: java, android

I am currently developing an Application to consistently running a *Service* which gets all received Messages and pushes them to Google Sheets. My *Service* includes an *Async Task* which is created once a Message is received. Here is the AsyncTask which is inside my Service class. The SMSListener is a *Broadcast Receiver* class.

SmsListener

```
public class SmsListener extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean RECEIVED = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            setRECEIVED(true);
            Log.d("DEBUGSMSLISTENER", "SMS is received.");
        }
    }

    public boolean isRECEIVED() {
        return RECEIVED;
    }

    public void setRECEIVED(boolean RECEIVED) {
        this.RECEIVED = RECEIVED;
    }

}
```

AsyncTask

```
static class AsyncPushTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Uri> {

    //Fields

    private AsyncPushTask(SmsListener listener, Context context, ContactManager manager, Context application) {
        smsListener = listener;
        contentResolver = context.getContentResolver();
        contactManager = manager;
        applicationContext = application;
    }

    @Override
    protected Uri doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        Log.d(TAG, "ASYNC BACKGROUND started");

        Log.d(TAG, "is received " + smsListener.isRECEIVED());
        //if (isPermitted() & smsListener.isRECEIVED()) {
        //if (true) {
        Log.d(TAG, "is permitted and received SMS TASK");
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox"), null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { // must check the result to prevent exception
//Do the work to push SMS to Google Sheets
```

The Code works as expected but sometimes, I cannot recreate the behavior, the First SMS in the inbox isnt recognized correctly, so that the pushed message equals the one that was pushed in the last cycle.

TY for the help.

Comment: Incoming messages are ultimately handled by the default SMS app, and that's going to take a moment to process and save them. You're likely doing your query too soon. If you don't want to mess with implementing some unknown delay interval, you can get the message from the `Intent` passed into `onReceive()`. I would also mention that you really shouldn't need a constantly running `Service`. A Receiver for the `SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` can be registered in the manifest, though certain devices might require the user to explicitly allow your app to run in the background, or specifically to receive SMS.

Comment: Thank you i implemented the same logic inside the  Broadcast Receiver and got the message from the intent. This seems to work fine as far as i can test it. Still i am wondering if there is any possibility to get this behavior testable under any circumstances?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you're asking.